# Where do you store user uploaded content within a Symfony 4 application?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a section within my site where the user can upload their own profile pictures which is stored in the output directory and tracked in the database like so:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(ProfileUpdateForm::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $firstname = $form->get('firstname')->getData();
        $lastname = $form->get('lastname')->getData();
        $picture = $form->get('profilepicture')->getData();

        if($picture == null)
        {
            $user
            ->setFirstName($firstname)
            ->setLastName($lastname);
        }
        else
        {
            $originalFilename = pathinfo($picture->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
            $safeFilename = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $originalFilename));
            $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$picture->guessExtension();

            try {
                $picture->move(
                    'build/images/user_profiles/',
                    $newFilename
                );
            } catch (FileException $e) {
                $this->addFlash("error", "Something happened with the file upload, try again.");
                return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
            }

            // updates the 'picture' property to store the image file name
            // instead of its contents
            $user
            ->setProfilePicture($newFilename)
            ->setFirstName($firstname)
            ->setLastName($lastname);
        }

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash("success", "Your profile was updated!");
        return $this->redirectToRoute('account');
    }

    return $this->render('account/profile.html.twig', [
        'profileform' => $form->createView()
    ]);
```

That issue I've found is that every time I compile my (local) project, the image is then deleted (because the public/build directory gets built by deleting and creating again).

If I'm not mistaken, isn't that how deployments work too? And if so, is that the right way to upload an image? What's the right way of going about this?

Comment: How on earth is this an opinion based question lol? Clearly what I'm doing is wrong since I'm new to Symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but your `public/` directory shouldn't be deleted.
If you're using Webpack Encore, then `public/build/` content is deleted and created again when you compile assets. But not `public/` itself.

For uploads, we create `public/upload/` directory.
Then, most of the time, we set some globals, which allow us to save the file name only.

Globals for Twig in `config/packages/twig.yaml` which "root" will be in your `public/` directory

```
twig:
    globals:
        app_ul_avatar: '/upload/avatar/'
        app_ul_document: '/upload/document/'
```

And globals for your controllers, repositories, etc in `config/services.yaml`

```
parameters:
    app_ul_avatar: '%kernel.root_dir%/../public/upload/avatar/'
    app_ul_document: '%kernel.root_dir%/../public/upload/document/'
```

It's handy because, as I just said, you only get to save the file name in the database.

Which mean that, if you got a `public/upload/img/` folder, and want to also generates thumbnails, you can then create `public/upload/img/thumbnail/` and nothing will change in your database, nor do you have to save an extra path.

Just create a new global `app_ul_img_thumbnail`, and you're set.

Then all you have to do is call your globals when you need them, and contact with the file name:

In Twig:

```
{{ app_ul_avatar~dbResult.filename }}
```

Or in Controller:

```
$this->getParameter('app_ul_avatar').$dbResult->getFilename();
```

Comment: You're correct about the public not being destroyed (just the build), I misspoke, and fixed my question. Let me try this out now!

Comment: I do have a question, I did do `{{app.ul.avatar}}` and I got an error of `Neither the property "ul" nor one of the methods "ul()", "getul()"/"isul()"/"hasul()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable".` What does this mean?

Comment: Most likely, twig think it's an array. I updated my answer to avoid this problem @Majo0od